# Trouble linking assembly program: File format not recognized

Tags: assembly, linker, 64-bit, nasm

I have the following simple assembly program (downloaded from [this website](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample_64.shtml)).:

```
        extern  printf          ; the C function, to be called

        section .data           ; Data section, initialized variables
msg:    db "Hello world", 0     ; C string needs 0
fmt:    db "%s", 10, 0          ; The printf format, "\n",'0'

        section .text           ; Code section.

        global main             ; the standard gcc entry point
main:                           ; the program label for the entry point
        push    rbp             ; set up stack frame, must be alligned

        mov rdi,fmt
        mov rsi,msg
        mov rax,0               ; or can be  xor  rax,rax
        call    printf          ; Call C function

        pop rbp                 ; restore stack

        mov rax,0               ; normal, no error, return value
        ret                     ; return
```

When I try to build from the command line using NASM I get no errors, and it creates the object file correctly. Then I link it using Mingw-w64 (ld) (because I am on a x64 machine) with command line option `-m i368pe`, but this fails with an error message: File format not recognized. After searching a bit, I found that this has to do with the fact that there I am trying to link a 32 bit object file with a 64 bit linker or the other way around. However, this does not make sense to me as I built the object file with the `-f win64` flag. Also, I believe `-m i386pe` is a 64 bit flag for linking, so what am I doing wrong here?

My commands for building/linking are:

- Build: `nasm -f win64 -o test.obj test.asm`
- Link: `ld test.obj -m i386pe -o test.exe`

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit machine why are you going out of your way to make a 32-bit executable?

Comment: I want to make a 64 bit executable, if that wansn't clear from the question

Comment: Why would setting the emulation linker to 386 help anything? Take the time to read up on what these options do rather than using them blindly.

Comment: And thanks for changing the title, I don't know why I made it that way

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding out why you'd use `i386pe` as the executable format. Normally you let the linker use the native version unless you're cross-compiling for another OS or ISA.

Comment: I tried leaving it out, but that still produces the same result. I got there because first I had other problems linking, and they seemed to be gone when I was using that option. Little did I know that I made a type in my input file path...

Comment: When you say "crashed" do you mean it actually executed and then crashed, or failed to start with an error? This code can't work unless it's linked to the C Standard Library because you're using the `printf` function, so I'd encourage you to look for a better `Makefile` template that defines how to compile this properly.

Comment: It executed and then crashed yes. I am currently not using any Makefile, do I need that?

Comment: A `Makefile` is a small script that can help recompile your program properly each time you make a change. It's a lot more reliable than copy-pasting the same commands into your shell.

Comment: I should probably use that indeed. I'm going to look for a good template on google and see if I can find anything

Comment: The `Makefile` acts as a recipe for compiling and once you find one that works, cherish it forever! These can be fussy to get right.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time. I'm reading an introduction to makefiles now and I'm going to try to get myself a good one after that

Comment: For 2-line build "process" you can just put those two lines into shell script (or DOS batch file), so you don't need to type it again and again (`make` is incredibly powerful and nice tool, but can take some time to start to use it effectively ... actually half of modern build tools were written by people who did misunderstood `make`). Not sure if `nasm -f win64` is enough, don't you have to use also `bits 64` directive in the source at the beginning? I do use that in linux to produce 64b linux binaries, even when the file format is elf64.

Comment: @Ped7g Still gives file format not recognized

Comment: well, I don't have windows to try myself, so maybe somebody else with your platform will read this and try it out.. it's probably some minor detail somewhere, try to get some working hello world example from some tutorial for nasm+64b win, if such thing exists (probably yes)... not sure, this is off my reach, haven't seen windows for quite some years and not willing to see them again. :)

Comment: @Ped7g: NASM `-f` options set the default bitness for ELF at least, I'd assume the same for `win64`.  You should *avoid* using `bits 64`, so you get an error message instead of weirdness if you use a 32-bit object file format.  It's more confusing when your code assembles + links, but then 64-bit machine code is decoded as 32-bit, where REX prefixes become inc/dec instructions!